# Minimum Spanning Tree Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a connected graph G=(V,E) V={1,2,...,n} [image] and a cost function c:E->R
and a second partial  graph G'=(V,T) where T={ for every vertex v∈ V find the neighbor with the minimum cost and add the new edge to T}

[image]
[image]

If G' graph has at least 2 connected components with the set of vertices [image] we consider the graph H where 
[image] iff the set of edges (from the initial graph G) [image] is not null.We define over the edges of H a cost function[image].

Let's say I choose V(H)={a,e,f} and E(H)={ae,af,fe}  and

```
E12={ab,bc,bd,ed} 
E23={eg,ef} E31={fc,fd}                            
c'(ae)=min{c(ab),c(bc),c(bd),c(ed)}=4
c'(af)=min{c(fc),c(fd)}=9
c'(fe)=min{c(eg),c(ef)}=8
```

Now for every edge e ∈ E(H) we note with e' the edge (from the original graph G)
for which this minimum is attained.
So e'={bc,df,eg} because bc=4 , df=9 and eg=8 and are the min edges that connect my components.
And I have a minimum spanning tree in H relative to the cost function c' and A' is the set of edges for this tree.

So A'={ae,fe} (I deleted the edge with the maximum cost=af from my graph H to create a min spanning tree)
and I have another set of edges A'={e'|e∈A'} and 
[image] is a min spanning tree in G relative to the function cost c.

But none of my edges from A' are the same with the ones from e'.

What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're implementing Boruvka's algorithm. If you look at the notation, it says there's an edge from one new node v<sub>C<sub>1</sub></sub> to a new node v<sub>C<sub>2</sub></sub> if there are a pair of nodes x ∈ C<sub>1</sub> and y ∈ C<sub>2</sub> that are adjacentnin the original graph G. In other words, there's an edge between two new nodes if the connected components they correspond to in G' are adjacent in G. The cost of the edge running between them is then the lowest of the costs of any of the edges running between those CC's in the original graph G.